# Hive Variable Substitution with function

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to to something like the following in Hive

set TODAY="2013-11-04"; //this works

SET TODAY = to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())); //this does not..

set TODAY;
TODAY=to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()))

Any suggestions?

Comment: yes, it would be great if HQL added a few control features, but for now, would have pass in from the shell e.g `hive --hiveconf TODAY=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")`

Answer (score 2):

```
SET TODAY = to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()));
```

This is not available in Hive.
What you can do is

```
select  concat ('set TODAY=',to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())),'\;') from testTableName limit 1 >>/path/to/HQL/file/fileName.sql
```

Now in the file **fileName.sql** you will see

```
set TODAY=2013-11-05;
```

The file **fileName.sql** need to be loaded before running the other dependent queries. That you can do by this:

```
hive -f hiveQueries.sql
```

You file **hiveQueries.sql** should contain something like this:

```
    use testDB;
    source /path/to/HQL/file/fileName.sql;
    select * from testTable where someColumn=${hiveconf:TODAY};
```

Hope this helps..:)