# Query issue with Hive

Tags: hive

I have a partitioned table in Hive with partitioned columns as e_year,e_month and e_day (all as strings). If i hardcode the values the query come out fine but if I try to make it more generic it gets stuck and times out. Could you please tell me what's the issue? The table is 5-6TB in size

Query:

```
select count(*),
       e_type,
       e_src_type
from   table1
where e_year=
      cast(substr(date_sub(From_unixtime(unix_timestamp()), 4),1,4) as string)
and   e_month=
      cast(substr(date_sub(From_unixtime(unix_timestamp()), 4),6,2) as string)
and  e_day=
     cast(substr(date_sub(From_unixtime(unix_timestamp()), 4),9,2) as string)
group by e_type,
         e_src_type
```

This comes out:

```
select  count(*),
        e_type, 
        e_src_type
from    table1
where   e_year='2015'
and     e_month='02'
and     e_day='02'
group by e_type,
        e_src_type
```

Comment: I saw that with functions in where clause,its not taking the partitions rather going for FTS. Can any one tell how to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to evaluate partitions upfront and use hive variables in a query, like below.

```
SET year='2015';
SET month='02';
SET day='02';

select  count(*),
        e_type, 
        e_src_type
from    table1
where   e_year==${hiveconf:year}
and     e_month=${hiveconf:month}
and     e_day=${hiveconf:day}
group by e_type,
        e_src_type;
```

Evaluating of variables is as bit tricky, similar case you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775040/hive-variable-substitution-with-function). Gl!